# Why is nginx returning a 502 when doing a `uwsgi_pass` to a linked docker container?

Tags: django, nginx, docker, uwsgi, docker-compose

I'm using *Docker Compose* to orchestrate a multi-container app composed of both a Django webapp and an nginx reverse-proxy.

I'm staring with a simple test-case, but I've already hit a roadblock.  The app *should* pass all requests to `/` over to the Django application by way of `uwsgi_pass` over a network socket (`frontend:8000`).

However, after starting the application with `docker-compose up` and seeing no error message, any request to `/` produces the following error message in the console:  `gateway_1  | 2016/01/11 15:45:12 [error] 8#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://172.17.0.2:8000", host: "192.168.99.100:8000"`

**My question is as follows:**  What might the problem be?  Replacing `uwsgi_pass frontend;` in the `location` block with `content_by_lua_file path/to/file.lua;` behaves as expected, so I suspect a problem with uWSGI over a container link, but I'm at a loss for where to look next.

Below are the relevant files:

## Docker Compose:  the 30,000-ft view

The `docker-compose.yml` file is as follows:

```
postgres:
    image: mystuff/app.testdb:latest
    expose:
        - "5432"
frontend:
    image: mystuff/app.frontend:latest
    expose:
        - "8000"
    environment:
        APP_DBCONN: "user=xxx dbname=xxx port=5432 host=postgres sslmode=require password=xxx"
        APP_ENV: "test"
gateway:
    image: mystuff/app.gateway:latest
    links:
        - frontend
    expose:
        - "8000"
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
```

## NGINX:  the reverse proxy

Below is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes 1;
user me;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:8000;  # assumption:  `frontend` is a known hostname thanks to docker-compose
    }

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass frontend;
            include uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is my `uwsgi_params` file:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

## uWSGI & Django:  the application server

`uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/app
wsgi-file = ./NFC/wsgi.py
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
master = true
processes = 1
threads = 2
uid = me
```

## Edits

### 1.  Log output with `http = 127.0.0.1:8000` in `uwsgi.ini`

```
$ cat /tmp/uwsgi.log 
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Wed Jan 13 12:09:44 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 03 January 2016 21:09:04
os: Linux-4.1.13-boot2docker #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 19:05:50 UTC 2015
nodename: default
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/srg
detected binary path: /home/srg/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/srg
your processes number limit is 1048576
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:8000 fd 7
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:38922 (port auto-assigned) fd 6
Python version: 2.7.11 (default, Jan  3 2016, 21:07:12)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1d37300
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 166144 bytes (162 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1d37300 pid: 173 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 173)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 210, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 211)
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
gateway "uWSGI http 1" has been buried (pid: 211)
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
```

Comment: try to set `http = 127.0.0.1:8000` in uWSGI file and connect to that socket directly from browser.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Should this replace the `socket` line?

Comment: Yes, because it uses same port. But you can use different port and leave both.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Sorry I should have been more clear ... Can I set `socket` to a different port *and* set `http`, or are the two entries mutually incompatible?

Comment: as I said, you can use both if they are on different port.

Comment: @GwynBleidD, You did.  Apologies... I'm going to grab some coffee and give that a whirl.

Comment: @GwynBleidD, I'm getting a connection refused error in my browser and no output in the terminal.  Where should I look next?

Comment: Probably your uwsgi logs. You can add logging using: `logger  = file:/path/to/logfle.log`.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I've posted my log output because I don't see anything going wrong there, but I'm still getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100593/discussion-between-gwynbleidd-and-blz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With that uWSGI configuration, especially with:

```
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
```

uWSGI will allow only local connection (which means from same docker, not from host or other dockers). To allow connections from outside of docker, you must change it to:

```
socket = :8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following property to your .ini config.

```
chmod-socket = 666
```